# Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, methodnotfound

I try to run my flutter aplication in VScode and I get these errors:

```
       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.8.10/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-4.6.1/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:263:9: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
  throw FallThroughError();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:11:20: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
  return internals.guardWebExceptions(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the     
class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
 - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from
 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart'
 ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib /src/action_code_info.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
'FallThroughError'.
        throw FallThroughError();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found:       
'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
```

I tried  to solve this problem deleting cache and reinstalling dependencies, but the problem persists.
What else can I do?